NetworkX planning algorithms with multigraphs: express paths as a sequence of edges (instead of nodes)?
I use NetworkX to run path planning algorithms on multigraphs. NetworkX expresses solution paths as sequences of nodes. This representation is ambiguous with multigraphs because neighbouring nodes might be connected by two or more edges; it's unclear which edges are part of the solution.
I can manually iterate over a solution path and search for the edge that is part of the solution at every step of the way, but this feels messy/wasteful.
Is there any way to get NetworkX to express paths as a sequence of edges instead of a sequence of nodes? Or a more elegant way to express paths as sequences of edges in a multigraph?
Toy example:
Consider the following (undirected) graph. It is a MultiGraph since vertices 1 and 2 are connected by more than one undirected edge. We are interested in traveling from vertex 0 to vertex 2.

NetworkX implementation:
import networkx as nx

edges = [
    (0,1,0, {'cost': 3}),
    (1,2,0, {'cost': 5}),
    (1,2,1, {'cost': 10}),
]

G = nx.MultiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(edges)

total_cost, path = nx.single_source_dijkstra(G, source=0, target=2, weight='cost')
print(total_cost)  # 8
print(path)        # [0, 1, 2]

The path shown is only the sequence of vertices along the solution, not a sequence of edges. When going from vertices 1 to 2, there is no indication of which edge to take. I can search among the edges between vertices 1 and 2 and retain the one with the lowest cost.
This procedure seems trivial in a toy problem, but becomes annoyingly time-consuming when planning across large graphs.

Could you provide a small toy example of the problem that can be reproduced? What function are you using?

Thank you very much for the reply! I added a toy example to my question.

Don't edges in NetworkX multigraphs have keys to distinguish them by default?

Yes they do. However I'm interested in identifying which edges are part of a shortest path. As shown in my example, NetworkX's shortest path algorithms express paths as a sequence of vertices, not a sequence of edges. So after obtaining the optimal path, extra work is needed to determine what edges are part of this optimal path.

If all you're doing is finding shortest paths, then you always want the edge with the lowest weight, right? For one query, it's probably quicker to select edges after the path is returned. For numerous queries, it might be worthwhile to convert the multigraph to a graph using only the min weight edge between vertices.

Indeed. In the actual problem I'm working with, these edge weights will change over time, so I would need to make that conversion every time before a planning query is made. One way or another, it seems like computations in addition to just the shortest path request is needed.
